# How do I create a table whereby the Foreign Keys (2) are part of a Composite Primary Key in another table (Oracle)?

Tags: sql, oracle, foreign-keys, data-modeling

I have two tables.

- Section (SectionNo, Semester, CourseID) <- I made all 3 attributes a Composite PK
- Registration (Registration-ID, StudentID, SectionNo, Semester) <- Registration_ID is a Surrogate Key and the remaining 3 attributes are supposed to be my Foreign Keys.

I have trouble creating the registration specifically when I want to reference the attributes 'SectionNo' and 'Semester' which are FK in the Registration table.

My code is as such :

```
CREATE TABLE REGISTRATION(  
Registration_ID Int NOT NULL,  
StudentID Int NOT NULL,  
SectionNo Int NOT NULL,  
Semester Varchar(25) NOT NULL,    
CONSTRAINT REGISTRATION_PK PRIMARY KEY(Registration_ID),  
CONSTRAINT REGISTRATION_FK1 FOREIGN KEY(StudentID)
  REFERENCES STUDENT(StudentID) ON DELETE CASCADE,  
CONSTRAINT REGISTRATION_FK2 FOREIGN KEY(SectionNo,Semester) 
  REFERENCES SECTION(SectionNo,Semester) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

However, when I run it on Oracle, the error I get is :

```
ORA-02270: no matching unique or primary key for this column-list
```

I have already created the Section table as :

```
CREATE TABLE SECTION(  
SectionNo Int NOT NULL,  
SEMESTER Varchar(25) NOT NULL,  
CourseID Varchar(25) NOT NULL,  
CONSTRAINT SECTION_PK PRIMARY KEY(SectionNo,Semester, CourseID),  
CONSTRAINT SECTION_FK1 FOREIGN KEY(CourseID)  
REFERENCES Course(CourseID)  
ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

There is no error creating the Section Table. Hence, I'm confused as to how am I to create the Registration table.

Would appreciate some help from you all.

Comment: This is a faq. Before considering posting please read the manual & google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. Reflect your research. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Answer (score 0):

```
PRIMARY KEY(SectionNo, Semester, CourseID)

FOREIGN KEY(SectionNo, Semester)
```

The problem is that you have incorrect column list in `REGISTRATION_FK2` foreign key constraint. The **column list of the foreign key** must exactly match with the **column list of the primary key it is referencing to**.

Primary Key `SECTION_PK` has column list `SectionNo, Semester, CourseID`, therefore, your foreign key must have the same columns.